# Wrong button image scaling in chrome

Tags: jquery, css, image, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Im having a really weird problem.

I created share buttons for social media websites.

The buttons are located on an element that comes in with an on-click slide. I provided the buttons with a custom image `(32x32px)`.

With up2date Firefox and IE10 versions everything works as it should, but chrome just resizes the images to `2x2px`. When I inspect the buttons with the DevTools it even tells me `"2x2px (Natural: 32x32px)"`.

Without the jquery slide the buttons get displayed correctly in chrome. Does anyone know why this happens and how can I fix it while keeping the slide?